# Integration problem with $e$ and $\ln$

Tags: integration

Can anyone help me solve this? I tried with integration with parts, but without luck. The function to be integrated is
$$\frac{e^{x+\ln x}}{x}$$

Comment: If you are still unclear with the answers, the problem is basically just algebra $\displaystyle\frac{e^{x+\ln x}}{x} = \frac{e^x \cdot e^{\ln x}}{x}= \frac{e^x \cdot x}{x}=e^x $ then we can simply integrate this to get $e^x+C$.

Answer (score 3):

it is not so difficult $$\frac{e^{x+\ln(x)}}{x}=e^x$$

Comment: ... but only for $x>0$.

Comment: yes it is right since we have $\ln(x)$

Comment: i would upvote you!!!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $e^{-x+\ln (-x)}/-x = e^{-x+\ln(x) + i \pi}/-x=e^{-x}$ (assuming $x>0$)

Comment: You don't need to assume $x>0$ whatsoever, only $x\neq{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $x=e^{\ln x}$.

$$\frac{e^{x + \ln x}}{x}=\frac{e^{x + \ln x}}{e^{\ln x}}=e^{x + \ln x-\ln x}=e^x$$

Comment: the result $e^x+C$ looks nicer